# How to display variables from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display variables from an array.I have tried it but not working.
My code

```
<?php
    $quesid = array();
    $quid = $_POST["qid"];
    print_r($quid);
    foreach ($que as $quid) {      
        $quesid = $que[0][$j];
        echo $quesid;
    }
?>
```

this is not working.
but `print_r($quid);` shows the array elements:

```
 Array ( ['1'] => 54 ['2'] => 55 ['3'] => 56 ['4'] => 57 ['5'] => 58 ['6'] => 59 ['7'] => 60 ['8'] => 64 ['9'] => 65 ['10'] => 66 ['11'] => 76 ['12'] => 77 ['13'] => 78 )
```

Comment: I can't see `$j` variable in your code. You need to define `$j=1` before loop and then you need to increment `$j++;` into your loop.

Comment: thankyou hardik for checking my question.WisdmLabs solves problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        $quid = $_POST["qid"];
        print_r($quid);
        foreach ($quid as $key=>$value) {      
        $quesid=$value;
        echo $quesid;}
        ?>
```

Comment: Check above foreach loop for your array.

Comment: Thankyou WisdmLabs.. can i use this foreach loop for fetching any array

Comment: Yes you can use this foreach loop for key=>value pair type array

Answer (score 0):

You have the `foreach` expression in the wrong order:

```
<?php 
$quids = $_POST["qid"]; 
foreach ($quids as $k=>$quid){ 
    echo $quid."<br>"; 
}
?>
```